# Connecting HP storageworks to Dell poweredge R720

Tags: dell-poweredge, sas, hp-storageworks

Can HP storageworks 1/8 G2 tape autoloader be connected to a Dell poweredge R720 server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. And that is very easy to discover with less than two minutes of research.

1. Check which interface the tape loader has.
2. Check is your server has a spare connector of this type.
3. If not, check if you have slot to add it.

[According to Dell](http://www.dell.com/us/enterprise/p/poweredge-r720/pd) your server has 7 PCIe slots:
One x16 full-length, full-height
Three x8 full-length, full-height
Three x8 half-length, half-height

At least one of those is likely to be free.